# Issues running a python 2.7 environment on anaconda 3

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I have created a python 2.7 environment with anaconda 3:

```
conda create python=2.7 -n py27
```

I activate the new environment but when i try to run python i get the following error:

```
File ..AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site.py", line 176 file=sys.stderr)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked the path variable and it looks fine.

```
C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27;
C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27\Library\bin;
C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27\Scripts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had these set up as environment variables and they seemed to have interfered with anaconda, when activating the py27 environment.

```
echo %PYTHONPATH%  
C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib

echo %PYTHONHOME%  
C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
```